# Certificate Upload in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: javascript, asp.net, file-upload, ssl-certificate

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC3 app. I have a page where I allow the user to upload a certificate. I was thinking of 2 options:

1. Encode the Certificate file to Base64 string in JavaScript and send it as a parameter in POST to the Server
2. Use some jQuery library to upload the cert (like a normal file upload)

It is a SSL Cert (I assume the size of SSL Certs should be in KBs. Am I right?). Since POST data's max size is 4MB by default, I am preferring option 1. Are there any other gotchas? Is there a recommended way to do this?

Thanks, Sornakumar S